# Setup could not install following component: Microsoft Application Error Reporting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-express

I was running `Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express Setup` on my `Windows 7`. But I am unable to complete the setup, due to the following error

[image]

> I didn't cancel the installation any time. I am the `administrator` of this machine. I also tried few things by referring sites like - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/a8da8e97-e4e2-416a-97f1-636c2dc1d4c1/

Any idea, what could be wrong?

My installation log is reporting the following error:

> [12/10/12,19:14:39] Microsoft Application Error Reporting: [2] CMsiComponent::Install() expects the setup file for Microsoft Application Error Reporting, but the file failed verification. [12/10/12,19:14:39] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467259. [12/10/12,19:14:40] ExpressUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Application Error Reporting is not installed.

Comment: Have you tried to collect installation logs and check what's wrong? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2009/05/20/collect.aspx

Comment: Hi @ArtemKoshelev: I checked `dd_error_vcs_xcor_100`log file and it says->`[12/10/12,19:14:39] Microsoft Application Error Reporting: [2] CMsiComponent::Install() expects the setup file for Microsoft Application Error Reporting, but the file failed verification.
[12/10/12,19:14:39] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467259.
[12/10/12,19:14:40] ExpressUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Application Error Reporting is not installed.`

Comment: Hi @ArtemKoshelev: And from `dd_install_vcs_xcor_100` log file I got -> `[12/10/12,19:14:29] Microsoft Application Error Reporting: File failed validation: e:\vcsexpress\.\wcu\watson\dw20shared.msi; error = 0x80091007`. I had used the same `iso` file on other machine a long way back. Could that be the reason?

Comment: I had this error due to trying to install from a network symbolic link, after copying the files locally it worked ok. Took ages to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your installation logs, and find the error message below:

[04/25/11,10:00:53] InstallReturnValue: GFN_MID Microsoft Application Error Reporting, 0x641
[04/25/11,10:00:53] Microsoft Application Error Reporting: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : Error: Installation failed for component Microsoft Application Error Reporting. MSI returned error code 1601

For the error code hex 0x641 / decimal 1601, it means ERROR_INSTALL_SERVICE_FAILURE, which translate to "The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed. This can occur if you are running Windows in safe mode, or if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed".

According to the error message, this issue should be related with your Windows Installer service.

Would you please help to check that the Windows Installer service is set to manual but not disable via the following steps:

Click Start menu, click Run, type services.msc in the Open text box, and then click OK.
In the Services (Local) list, right-click Windows Installer, and then click Properties.
If the Startup type drop-down list is set to a value of Disable, select the Manual option from the Startup type drop-down list, and then click OK.
Click the File menu, and then click Exit.
You can try download and install the latest Windows Installer 4.5 Redistributable

ALso, please refer the below link in the Windows installer issues section to know more about fixing some issues related with the service.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2438651
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315346
Additionally, I've noticed that you have some removable devices connect to your computer while installing, please also remove them during the installation.

If there are any updates, please feel free to let me know.